# How to split character column at divider and create new binary columns?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df_cat` looking like this:

```
dput(df_cat)

structure(list(Name = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", 
"Name6"), Category = c("App", "App, Comms_2", "App, Comms, Tech", 
"App, Tech", "Comms, Tech", "BS, Tech")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I want to split column `Category` at the divider **","** and create new columns for each input with the original column name in front. These columns should be binary and indicate, whether a row contains this category (**1**) or not (**0**):

```
Name   Category_App  Category_Comms_2  Category_Tech  Category_BS
Name1  1             0                 0              0
Name2  1             1                 0              0
Name3  1             1                 1              0
Name4  1             0                 1              0
Name5  0             1                 1              0
Name6  0             0                 1              1
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this in a dataset, that has over 23k rows and over 100 different categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done easily with `separate_rows` and `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
   separate_rows(Category) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Category, values_from = Category,
               names_prefix = "Category_",
               values_fn = function(x) 1, values_fill = 0) %>%
   select(-row)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  Name  Category_App Category_Comms Category_Tech Category_BS
  <chr>        <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Name1            1              0             0           0
2 Name2            1              1             0           0
3 Name3            1              1             1           0
4 Name4            1              0             1           0
5 Name5            0              1             1           0
6 Name6            0              0             1           1
```

If you want to retain the original `category` column, add it with `bind_cols`:

```
df %>%
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
   separate_rows(Category) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Category, values_from = Category,
               names_prefix = "Category_",
               values_fn = function(x) 1, values_fill = 0) %>%
   select(-row) %>%
   bind_cols(., df %>% select(Category))
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  Name  Category_App Category_Comms Category_Tech Category_BS Category        
  <chr>        <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>           
1 Name1            1              0             0           0 App             
2 Name2            1              1             0           0 App, Comms      
3 Name3            1              1             1           0 App, Comms, Tech
4 Name4            1              0             1           0 App, Tech       
5 Name5            0              1             1           0 Comms, Tech  
6 Name6            0              0             1           1 BS, Tech
```

Comment: I think the row number isn't even needed. `separate_rows()` seems superseded, so perhaps go with `df |>  separate_longer_delim(Category, delim = regex(",\\s?")) |>  pivot_wider(names_from = Category, values_from = Category) |> 
  mutate(across(!Name, \(x) !is.na(x)))` instead?

Comment: How can I retain the original column ```Category``` in the dataset as well?

Comment: Just add `bind_cols(., df %>% select(Category))` to the pipe (preceded by `%>%` of course)

Comment: I get the error "Error in select(., Category): Can't subset columns that don't exist"

Comment: Please check out the edited solution; there's no error there

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Works on my test dataset, however, for the real one I get the error "Error in UseMethod("select") :
no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "function"" - any idea why that could be?

Comment: not unless you post a snippet of your real data, for example with `(dput(head(REALDATA))`

Comment: Found the mistake. One more question - I only want to split the strings at the comma, not at any other divider. Right now, for my actuals dataset, it splits columns at all kinds of dividers (e.g. "_") - how can I only split at commas? - See edited dput()

Comment: Just specify this in the call to `separate_rows`:  `separate_rows(Category, sep = ",")`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the possible categories up front, you could even just hard-code them:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
          ~Name,          ~Category,
        "Name1",              "App",
        "Name2",       "App, Comms",
        "Name3", "App, Comms, Tech",
        "Name4",        "App, Tech",
        "Name5",      "Comms, Tech",
        "Name6",         "BS, Tech"
        )

df |> 
  mutate(
    Category_App = str_detect(Category, "App"),
    Category_Comms = str_detect(Category, "Comms"),
    Category_Tech = str_detect(Category, "Tech"),
    Category_BS = str_detect(Category, "BS")
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>   Name  Category         Category_App Category_Comms Category_Tech Category_BS
#>   <chr> <chr>            <lgl>        <lgl>          <lgl>         <lgl>      
#> 1 Name1 App              TRUE         FALSE          FALSE         FALSE      
#> 2 Name2 App, Comms       TRUE         TRUE           FALSE         FALSE      
#> 3 Name3 App, Comms, Tech TRUE         TRUE           TRUE          FALSE      
#> 4 Name4 App, Tech        TRUE         FALSE          TRUE          FALSE      
#> 5 Name5 Comms, Tech      FALSE        TRUE           TRUE          FALSE      
#> 6 Name6 BS, Tech         FALSE        FALSE          TRUE          TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: In my real data set I have more categories than just the ones chosen here so I dont want to hardcode all of them

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, unlist(strsplit(Category, "(,| )+")), by = Name
   ][, dcast(.SD, Name ~ paste0("Category_", V1), length)]

#      Name Category_App Category_BS Category_Comms Category_Tech
#    <char>        <int>       <int>          <int>         <int>
# 1:  Name1            1           0              0             0
# 2:  Name2            1           0              1             0
# 3:  Name3            1           0              1             1
# 4:  Name4            1           0              0             1
# 5:  Name5            0           0              1             1
# 6:  Name6            0           1              0             1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

# get vector of all the possible categories

all_categories <- df_cat$Category %>% 
                   str_split(",") %>%      # split at comma
                   unlist() %>%            # convert from list to vector
                  str_squish() %>%         # remove excess white space
                    unique()               # find unique values


# loop through all the categories 
for( category in all_categories){
  
  # create a column for each category
  # Then check for the category in the Category column
  df_cat[,category] <- str_detect(df_cat$Category,category) %>%      
                        as.numeric()               # convert TRUE/FALSE to 0/1
  
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R you could do:

```
a <- table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df$Category, "[, ]+"), df$Name))[2:1])

data.frame(df, as.data.frame.matrix(a), row.names = NULL)

   Name         Category App BS Comms Tech
1 Name1              App   1  0     0    0
2 Name2       App, Comms   1  0     1    0
3 Name3 App, Comms, Tech   1  0     1    1
4 Name4        App, Tech   1  0     0    1
5 Name5      Comms, Tech   0  0     1    1
6 Name6         BS, Tech   0  1     0    1
```